# Why is the product quantity in Magento 2.3 actually zero?

Tags: magento2.3.0

I set the version of my product to a positive number, but when I go to the product page in frontend it's quantity is zero. Can anyone explain why? You can see it underlined in red in the following image: 
[image]

My Magento version is 2.3.0

Comment: version and quantity is different

Answer (score 0):

Do a reindex and a cache cleaning and the quantity should update if you set it on the product edit page.

Edit:

Run these in the shell as your magento user.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```

Comment: unfortunately this commnads dose not work for me !